# java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() finding the "real" interfaces

Tags: java

I am a little confused regarding the return values from NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().  I am trying to filter through the list of NetworkInterface objects to figure out which are "real" (backed by actual hardware).  The code looks like...

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while ( e.hasMoreElements() ) {
    NetworkInterface iface = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
    if ( !iface.isLoopback() && !iface.isVirtual() ) {
        byte[] macAddress = iface.getHardwareAddress();
        String message = String.format(
            "%s %s parent: %s",
            iface.getName(),
            byteArrayToHexString( macAddress ),
            iface.getParent() );
        System.out.println( message );
    }
}
```

...and the output like...

```
vnic1 00 1C 42 00 00 09  parent: null
vnic0 00 1C 42 00 00 08  parent: null
en1 60 33 4B 20 C4 97  parent: null
```

I know that the "vnic1" and "vnic0" ones aren't "real" (they got put there by Parallels to support a VM I sometimes run on this machine).  Is there a way through NetworkInterface that I can detect the not "real" ones or are they effectively indistinguishable from their actual counterparts, like "en1"?  I would hate to have to resort to becoming dependent upon name like "its real if its name is en0 or en1".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look up the first half of the MAC, as it is the vendor code.  The majority of vendors probably make physical or virtual (not both) devices.

You won't hit 100% of cases with this approach, but it might be "good enough" for your use.

It also won't help you if someone spoofs the MAC address.

What are you trying to do here?  If you explain your ultimate goal, maybe there is another approach.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to get rich quick and check out of this game, but that doesn't matter right now.  I want to get the bytes of the MAC address to try to seed the creation of a UUID.  The java.util.UUID by default is just Random numbers, I was wondering if it could be made better by using the MAC address and I knew Java 6 made that available.  That's where I'm going with this; MAC address to seed UUID.

Comment: The random UUID is plenty good enough for all reasonable purposes.  Inventing your own way of seeding UUIDs is almost certainly going to make things worse, unless you've done all the math to show that your scheme is better...  Stick with UUID.randomUuid()

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, but have you tried [NetworkInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html).[isVirtual()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#isVirtual%28%29)? From the documentation:

> Returns whether this interface is a virtual interface (also called subinterface). Virtual interfaces are, on some systems, interfaces created as a child of a physical interface and given different settings (like address or MTU). Usually the name of the interface will the name of the parent followed by a colon (:) and a number identifying the child since there can be several virtual interfaces attached to a single physical interface.

Comment: The code already filters out isVirtual() and isLoopback(), so in that sense the vnics are "real".  Further, they've got null parents, so that discriminator is no good either.  This minor problem has stretched my understanding of MAC address.  Its like you can just assign one.

Comment: You can indeed just assign one, mac addresses are not unforgeable. :)

Comment: However, part of the mac address is a vendor code. “001C42” is the vendor code for “Parallels, Inc.” so a small database of vendors of virtual adpaters might be just what you need.